# Get certain length of a web page to the server

Tags: php

I am using fopen to get a web page's HTML output, aiming for the "Head" part for some information there (meta tags). The problem is that the script takes forever to load the "whole" page then parse only the head part for the needed info.

Is there a way to get a certain length of the page that guarantees a faster processing?

I am using this:

```
$page = @fopen($_url, "r");
while (!feof($page)) {
   $content .= fgets($page, 4096);
}
fclose($page);
```

Comment: You should first figure out how long each step is taking to find out which step or steps need to be streamlined. If the "parsing" is taking the longest, finding another download method won't remedy that.

Comment: For things like this I strongly recommend putting the data you want in a header, and then using the http `HEAD` instead of `GET`. Of course, that won't work if you're not the creator of the HTML pages.

Answer (score 2):

You can only get information until you find some specific text.  This is the case-sensitive version, which will perform better than insensitive.  If you expect your site to always use `'</head>'` and not any variations (e.g. `</HEAD>`), this will be best.

```
<?php

// I tested on this page.
$_url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466384/get-certain-length-of-a-web-page-to-the-server';
$page = @fopen($_url, "r");
$content = '';

while(!feof($page) && !strpos($content, '</head>')){
    $content .= fgets($page, 4096);
}
fclose($page);

echo $content;

?>
```

To make it insensitive change `strpos` to `stripos`.  The worst case would be never finding the closing tag, which results in the entire page being downloaded -- that's not that bad.